# Why does "(1 + 1.0)" have the type "Fractional a => a" and not "Num a => a"?

Tags: haskell, types

Since:

- `1` has the type `Num a => a`
- `1.0` has the type `Fractional a => a`

Why does `1 + 1.0` have the type `Fractional a => a`?

This seems strange to me because `1` is not fractional. Only `1.0` is fractional. So, how did `1` turn into fractional and get combined with `1.0` to form a fractional?

Since only `Num` has the `+` operator, it would seem more natural to me if `1.0` turned into `Num`, got combined with `1` to produce a final `Num`, although that would be strange too, because we would lose information going from `1.0` to `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type classes are very much **not** like OO classes, this can't be overemphasized.

In particular, “if `1.0` turned into `Num`” doesn't make any sense. `Num` is a type class, not a type, so nothing can ever “turn into a `Num`”. In fact, nothing ever turns into something else at all in Haskell – everything has a concrete type, that is fixed.

Now you ask, how do polymorphic functions work then? Well, it's called *parametric* polymorphism for a reason: what seems to be an “arbitrary type `a`” is really a *type parameter*. Like a function parameter, these aren't variables in the sense that they can ever change their value after the fact, but they are variable in the sense that the caller of the function is allowed to choose any particular “type value” for `a` – provided it fulfills the type-class constraint.

So in a sense, the literal `1` is a function: it accepts a *type argument* `a`, and returns a value `1 :: a`. What it requires is that `a` is in class `Num`.

Then we have `(+)` and `1.0`, both of which also need that same `a` argument. `(+)` again requires `Num`, nothing new; but `1.0` requires `Fractional a`. So all in all, `1 + 1.0` is a function that accepts “three copies of” the type argument `a`, and requires

- `Num a`
- `Num a`
- `Fractional a` – which also requires `Num a` because `Num` is superclass of `Fractional`.

It would be pretty awkward if we actually had to write the type out as

```
(1 + 1.0) :: (Num a, Num a, Fractional a, Num a) => a
```

so it is allowed to leave out the redundant constraints, only leaving `Fractional a`, which implies all the rest. What we can't do is only leave one of the `Num` constraints, because that would not imply `Fractional`.

Answer (score 10):

Every Fractional is a `Num`, but not every `Num` is a `Fractional`. So if we have a `Num` like `1`, it could either be a `Fractional` (because some `Num`s are `Fractional`s) or it could not be. However `1.0` can only be a `Fractional`, it definitely can't be some other `Num` like `Integer`.

So when the compiler sees that you add 1 to a `Fractional`, it realizes that `1` must be a `Fractional` as well in this case - otherwise you'd not be allowed to add it to a `Fractional`.

---

Here's a similar example that only involves user-defined type classes instead of `Num`s. Maybe this makes things clearer for you:

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: a

class Foo a => Bar a where
  bar :: a
  combine :: a -> a -> a
```

Through the above type classes we now have the following methods:

```
foo :: Foo a => a
bar :: Bar a => a
combine :: Bar a => a -> a -> a
```

So now let's try to combine `foo` and `bar` like this:

```
combine foo bar
```

This is roughly equivalent to you trying to add `1` (of type `Num a => a`) and `1.0` (of type `Fractional a => a`) in your example. And just like your example, this works fine and has the type `Bar a => a`.

Comment: You write: "So if we have a Num like 1, it could either be a Fractional (because some Nums are Fractionals) or it could not be." Okay, but the question is, how do you know that 1 can be a Fractional? This is a legitimate quesiton because you told me that 1 could either be or not be a Fractional. Is what's going on here some particular magic about Num that Haskell has a special treatment for, or is this something more general about type classes and functions? Please elaborate.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser That follows directly from the statement "Every Fractional is a Num", which we know because `Fractional` is defined as `class Num a => Fractional a where ...`.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. "Every Fractional is a Num" tells you that every Fractional is a Num, not that every Num is a Fractional. 1 is Num. I'm really confused now. To put it differently: Suppose I create my own type that is an instance of Num. How could a value of this type become Fractional? By magic? Maybe Haskell is doing some special magic in the case of 1 that wouldn't apply for a value of my own Num type?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser There's no special magic. And you're right, not every Num is a fractional. For example if you wrote `1 :: Integer`, it would not be a Fractional and writing `(1 :: Integer) + 1.0` would be an error. But since you didn't specify which type you want `1` to be, Haskell knows that it can choose whichever type works (as long as the type implements `Num` of course), which is why `1 + 1.0` works. I'll edit my answer to add an example that only involves user-defined type classes, so you can see that no num-specific magic is involved.

Comment: When this conversion occurs, is there a change the memory size? Is this conversion hidden in the compiler, or can it seen as haskell code?

Answer (score 2):

- Number `1` (which technically stands for `fromInteger` applied to the `Integer` value `1`) belongs to all the types in class `Num`.
- All the types in class `Fractional` belong to class `Num` as well.

Ergo,

Number `1` belongs to all the types in class `Fractional`.

Comment: `1 :: Num a => a`, so there's no implicit call to `fromInteger 1`. The compiler refines the type of `1` at the call site to `Fractional a => a` since `(+ 1.0) :: Fractional a => a -> a`.

Comment: @acomar There is an implicit call to `fromInteger`, which is why `1` can have the type `Num a => a`.

Comment: @sepp2k: That would imply `1 :: Integer` or something like it in order to be converted up to a `Num a => a`. How would you observe such a thing?

Comment: @acomar I didn't understand what you meant by "something like it" in your first sentence, but you observe `fromInteger` being called by defining your own type `MyNum` that implements `Num`, defining `fromInteger` is non-sensical way (and/or using Debug.Trace.trace in your `fromInteger` implementation) and then observing that writing `1 :: MyInt` does indeed invoke your `fromInteger` function.

Comment: @sepp2k: I meant that `1` would need to be passed to `fromInteger` monomorphically at some type. `Integer` is only one candidate. And thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @acomar Quoting the Haskell report - 6.4.1: "An integer literal represents the application of the function fromInteger to the appropriate value of type Integer." This is how the report makes integer literals polymorphic.

Comment: @acomar: a more correct statement might have been “`1` technically stands for `fromInteger literal1`, where `literal1 :: Integer` has value 1”, instead of “`1` stands for `fromInteger 1`”.